# Tab Pages Control Type used in IPad Apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, user-interface

What kind of controls are used in the photo in the link below i pointed to them with red arrows, its outline+ App, couldn't find any equivalent to it in Xcode.

Kindest Regards
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49071490/onenote_note_app_outline_plus_for_ipad_1.jpg

Comment: It's hard to say seeing as these are completely custom UI elements, but my best guess is that on the left you're looking at either a UITableView or possibly just UIButton's and the arrow in the top right is likely either once again just UIButton's or a UISegmentedControl.

Answer (score 0):

The longer arrow left below most probably points to an UITableViewCell which represents one cell in the UITableView, used as a menu. It is customized, though. No control in Xcode that looks like that out of the box.

Concerning the other arrow, iOS does not provide tab bar controls like in a browser. They are custom built from the ground with what you see in Xcode. A lot of thinkable possibilities to achieve that.

Comment: For the tab bar, many solutions on cocoacontrols, including : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mhtabbarcontroller. Have a look over there